# putObject exception. Possibly due to publicRead

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting uncaught exception that cannot be caught using try/catch (possibly because it's running on a different thread) when doing a `putObject`. The problem is intermittent, I haven't found the pattern yet. It's possible that this problem starts happening when I set the ACL to `publicRead`.

I am on the latest SDK version 1.7.1.

Here's the code:

```
AmazonS3Client *S3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:kAWSAccessKey withSecretKey:kAWSSecretKey];
S3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];
S3PutObjectRequest *S3POR = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:imageKey inBucket:kS3SignatureBucket];
S3POR.delegate = self;
S3POR.cannedACL = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
S3POR.contentType = @"image/png";
S3POR.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageData);
[S3 putObject:S3POR];
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to your question, but you can try to use my code instead:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3Client = [ [ AmazonS3Client alloc ] initWithAccessKey:strAccessKey withSecretKey:strSecretKey ];
s3Client.endpoint = [ AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:EU_WEST_1 ];
s3Client.maxRetries = 1;
s3Client.timeout = 60;

S3TransferManager *s3TransferManager = [ [ S3TransferManager alloc ] init ];
s3TransferManager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;
s3TransferManager.s3 = s3Client;

NSString *keyImage = //... here I generate a key

S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [ [ S3PutObjectRequest alloc ] initWithKey:keyImage inBucket:self.s3BucketName ];
putObjectRequest.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
putObjectRequest.data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( image, 0.5f );
putObjectRequest.cannedACL = [ S3CannedACL publicRead ];

putObjectRequest.delegate = self;
[ s3TransferManager upload:putObjectRequest ];
```

Also do not forget to keep strong reference to AmazonS3Client and S3TransferManager until upload will be completed!

Comment: What's the difference between using `S3TransferManager` and just what I did? Also, you said to keep a strong reference of `AmazonS3Client` and `S3TransferManager`, but your code doesn't seem to do so?

Comment: @pixelfreak Re:"What's the difference between using S3TransferManager and just what I did?" - Main difference - my code works. If you want -  you can look inside S3 framework to check is it really necessary.

Comment: @pixelfreak Re:"your code doesn't seem to keep strong references" - I have simplified my code to make it more readable. My original code is 3 times longer. Just create properties and add something like `self. s3Client = s3Client; self.s3TransferManager = s3TransferManager`.